# Find index of cells containing my string then separate this index to new cell

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have a cell array (3-by-3) in which every cell contains a string. I would like to find the indexes of the cells containing a specific string then separate this indexes to new cell array. I need this:

```
originalData={1 2 3;'?' 4 5 ; '?' 6 7}
new1={1 2 3} %// that doesn't contain my string.
new2={'?' 4 5;'?' 6 7} %// that contains my string
```

I used the following code:

```
cellfind = @(string)(@(cell_contents)(strcmp(string,cell_contents)));
cells = cellfun(cellfind('?'),originalData);
```

How to separate this index to new cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should give you the separated data (if separating by rows is meant):

```
new1 = originalData(~any(cells,2),:)
new2 = originalData(any(cells,2),:)
```

Comment: Thanks , that's what i ment